# Radio buttons getting selected automatically for all the rows of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of Conditions for which the user has to click yes or no for each condition. Using ng-repeat to show all the condition lists and a column with radio buttons for 'Yes' and 'No' pertaining to that code. The choice of selecting yes or no is independent of choice of another row. **When I mark a certain row with 'yes' , all the rows are being marked automatically 'yes'**. Ideal behavior is the initial radio button values should be empty by default and should be able to select yes or no for each row.
Can somebody please help with the mistake that am doing here ? Thanks.

```
<div ng-repeat= "person in myService.codeDetail">
 <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="radio">
            <input 
                   type="radio"
                   name= "radio{{$index}}"
                   id=""
                   data-ng-model= "model.isChecked"
                   ng-value="true"
                   ng-click="myService.updateList(patient.code)"
              >
            <label for="radio{{$index}}">Yes</label> 
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <input
                   type="radio"
                   name="radio{{$index}}"
                   id=""
                   data-ng-model="model.isChecked"
                   ng-value="false"
                   ng-click="myService.updateList(person.code)"                  
            >
            <label for="radio{{$index}}">No</label> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

Json Object used to pull the code, description from

```
     { "totalCount" : 48, "count" : 3, "offset" : 0, "limit" : 3,
        "codeDetail" : 
     {
     "codeList" : [{"Icd" : "250.42", "description" : "type 2", "date": "11/28/2015"},
     {"Icd" : "250.41", "description" : "type 1", "date": "11/27/2015"},
     {"Icd" : "250.40", "description" : "type 0 ", "date": "11/26/2015"}]
}
```

}

angular Controller :

```
   $scope.model = {}; // model object from service to store data
   $scope.myService = myService // binding angular service class to scope

   myService.updateList = function() {}; // a method in angular service
```

[image]

Comment: you must define data-ng-model for radio button as array

Comment: please add myService.codeDetail json object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **$index**:

Then, turn the data-ng-model into an array of true or false values and pass the index into into the data-ng-model like this:

```
data-ng-model = "model.isChecked[$index]"
```

And then your array can live in on scope like this:

```
scope.model.isChecked[$index] = [null, null... for how many questions you have]
```

Also, on a best-practices note, you should leverage the person object you are creating in the ng-repeat.  You can have the person's answers stored as a *property*  of this 'person' object as such:

data-ng-model = "person.answer" or something similar / more semantic.

One more note, you might take a look at angular's documentation regarding radio buttons, seems you could bring them more into line with angular's preferred implementation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this- This seems to solve the binding problem. Next I need to find a way to see all the rows are marked either yes / no. Checking on each row is "required", otherwise the submit in my form would be disabled. I will seek your help if needed, thanks.

Comment: @Rk Reddy Bairi Because you are initializing the array with 'null' if you are following my example then you can check upon form submission if any  value in the array === null (do a for loop or model.isChecked.forEach method) return a box that tells the user to make sure they complete the form.

Answer (score 3):

It is because your **data-ng-model= "model.isChecked"** is same for all the radio input in ng-repeat .

Use somthing like this :  **data-ng-model= "model['isChecked'_{{$index}}]"**

OR

Have an array like

```
$scope.someVariable =['radio1','radio2' ....]
```

and use it like this  :

> data-ng-model= "someVariable[$index]"

Comment: Can you help me know how that can be made dynamic ?

Comment: use somthing like this :  data-ng-model= "model['isChecked'_{{$index}}]"

Comment: @p2. when user select a radio button example yes the no radio button also select.

Comment: have different data-ng-model for yes and no , example  : for YES  data-ng-model= "model['isChecked_yes_'{{$index}}]" and for NO  data-ng-model= "model['isChecked_no_'{{$index}}]" . using this u will have different ng-data-model for reach nr-repeat and YES/NO radio button.

Answer (score 1):

you must have code similar this

i added a field to your json object that display and i think if yous use checkbox here is better.

```
 "codeList" : 
    [
     {"Icd" : "250.42", "description" : "type 2", "date": "11/28/2015","check":true OR false},
     {"Icd" : "250.41", "description" : "type 1", "date": "11/27/2015"},
     {"Icd" : "250.40", "description" : "type 0 ", "date": "11/26/2015"}
   ]
 } 
}
```

then in your html view you can define radio button model as this.

```
 <input 
   type="checkbox"
   name= "checkBox{{$index}}"
   id=""
   data-ng-model= "person.check"
   ng-value="true"
    ng-click="myService.updateList(patient.code)"
 >
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple this is because your data-ng-model is same for all.

So just modify it by the following code:

```
<input type="radio"
       name="radio{{$index}}"
       id=""
       data-ng-model="model.isChecked[$index]"
       ng-value="false"
       ng-click="myService.updateList(person.code)"                  
       >
```

Try this, it will work.